# VBA Search through directory for word documents containing string

Tags: vba

I'm attempting to write a macro for VBA that will search through a file directory based on a specific string you tell it to search for, but only if the string is present within a range of cells.

I've got the majority of the function working so far, however the issue lies with getting the program to actually return a document.

```
Public Function Method2(ByVal rngl As Range, ByVal strSearch As Variant)

Dim directory As String

Dim fileName As String

Dim objWord

Dim objDoc

Dim rng1 As Range

directory = "S:\File Recipes\NEW IWAVE RECIPES"

fileName = "test"

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set rng1 = Range("A:A").find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Product Codes Found!"

    fileName = Dir(directory & "*.docx")

    MsgBox (fileName)

   ' Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(fileName)

    objWord.Visible = True
Else
    MsgBox "Product Codes Not Found!"
End If
End Function
```

As far as I am aware the issue is with:

```
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.docx")
```

as nothing is fed back by:

```
MsgBox (fileName)
```

even when a string is found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a slash on the end of `"S:\File Recipes\NEW IWAVE RECIPES"` else your path is garbled, `fileName` is empty because there is no matching file. Note that dir() does not return the full path so you probably also need `objWord.Documents.Open(directory & fileName)`.

Comment: Adding the slash made it a complete file path and fixed the issue, the msgbox is now returning the proper files. Thank you for the help!